# Cache gradle dependencies, Travis CI

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

I'm trying to cache the dependencies for a private Travis CI repository, does Travis have some mechanism specific for gradle, or do I have to cache specific directories?

**.travis.yml:**

```
language: groovy

jdk:
  - openjdk7

env:
- TERM=dumb

before_install:
- cd application
- chmod +x gradlew

script:
- ./gradlew build
```

**Relevant parts of last working build:**

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip

......................................................................................................................................................................................

Unzipping /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/2pk0g2l49n2sbne636fhtlet6a/gradle-2.1-bin.zip to /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/2pk0g2l49n2sbne636fhtlet6a

Set executable permissions for: /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/2pk0g2l49n2sbne636fhtlet6a/gradle-2.1/bin/gradle

Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mycila/xmltool/xmltool/3.3/xmltool-3.3.pom

...
```

Would adding:

```
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle
```

work? or perhaps:

```
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#Projects-Using-Gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to cache at least `~/.gradle/wrapper` and `~/.gradle/caches`, but I'd probably start out with `~/.gradle`. (If necessary, the location of the latter can be changed by setting the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable). When upgrading to a newer Gradle version, the cache structure may change, so it might make sense to invalidate the cache from time to time.

PS: Please don't double-post here and on the Gradle forums (either is fine).

Answer (score 18):

Add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```

It is documented in Travis documentation at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#projects-using-gradle

Answer (score 6):

Probably you should add `sudo: false` to your `.travis.yml`, because caching is not available for public repositories. It will prevent you from using `sudo`, `setid`, `setgid`, but it allows caching mechanism!

But I have found that caching `$HOME/.gradle/caches` is not a very good variant, because the file `$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock` is changed every build, so Travis would repack the cache every time, and do full upload of that cache. That is slower for me than downloading all my dependencies. So maybe it would be better specify something else than `$HOME/.gradle/caches`.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it just comments that ~/.gradle/caches is not a good answer :(

Answer (score 3):

I just added the following folders:

```
- $HOME/.gradle/wrapper
- $HOME/.gradle/native
- $HOME/.gradle/daemon
- $HOME/.gradle/caches/jars-1
- $HOME/.gradle/caches/2.3
```

Adding the .gradle/caches will create a new cache file every build. 
Don't forget to change 2.3 to your gradle version.

Comment: Sure, check this one for instance: https://github.com/uphold/uphold-sdk-android/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the lines below into your .travis.yml :

```
before_cache:
  - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```

You can obtain more information [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/issues/358).

Answer (score 2):

As of version `3.5.1` the simplest and most effective way is to just cache the `caches/modules-2` and `caches/wrapper` directory. Caching whole `caches` directory adds too many files and it causes greater delay. You still need to to delete `modules-2.lock` file.

```
before_cache:
  - rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
cache:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```